# X-axis on Hover show title in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having a Grouped Stacked Column chart, when user points/hover on x-axis label complete label should be displayed. How can i do this without using formatter property in XAxis block.  Here is the fiddle [fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lu7bzmn/1/). In the Snippet i'm adding ellipses when the label is big.

TIA

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Appleeeeeeeeeee','Bateeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee','Catdafafda','Dogasdfasfa','Elephantadasfasd'],
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                y: 8,
                formatter: function() {
                    var xlabel = this.value,
                        formatted = xlabel.length > 10 ? xlabel.substring(0, 7) + '...' : xlabel;
                    console.log(formatted + " xAxislabel");
                    return formatted;
                },
                overflow: 'justify',
                align: 'left',
                rotation: 39
            },

            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false
                //tickPositions: [0]

        },
```

Comment: You can prepare a div positioned absolutely, then use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension to catch events on labels. Inside function show value.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, I'll try adding this plugin and update you. I'm using it in jasper and is there any possibility of doing it without using any plugin.

Comment: You can also handle the mouseover and mouseout event. I tried doing so and the updated fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/3Lu7bzmn/4/. I know it doesn't completely solve your problem. But I thought it might give you some hints towards your solution. Hover the mouse on the barcharts to see that the labels are getting expanded. But there is no much space to hold the long label. We need to find a solution for that. Hence not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @SherinMathew i appreciate your effort and got some idea on how to implement it. If i'm success in that approach i'll let you know or post as an answer.